# Iterating over hashmap with streams with condition

Tags: java, java-stream

So I have this loop

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> val : map.entrySet()) {
        if (val.getValue() >= 10 && !Objects.equals(val.getKey(), " ") && val.getKey().length() > 3) {
            stats = stats + val.getKey().toLowerCase() + " - " + val.getValue() + "\n";
        }
    }
```

Now I want to get rid of for loop and if condition using streams. How can I do this?

Comment: If you want a more equivalent stream, try `map.entrySet().stream()` to stream over the map entries. You would want to use `Stream#filter` to include only results that satisfy your `if` statement, and then finally use `Stream#forEach` to iterate the results. Using `Map#forEach` directly will really be no different than the for loop. Also, you can use `Stream#filter` multiple times, to specify the conditions separately.

Comment: I would `map` the entries to their respective `String`, and then use `Collectors.joining`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here could be an approach:

```java
String stats = map.entrySet().stream()
        // keep only the entries you're interested in:
        .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().length() > 3 && entry.getValue() >= 10)
        // serialise entries one by one:
        .map(entry -> entry.getKey().toLowerCase() + " - " + entry.getValue())
        // join:
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many approaches, here is one.

- first some test data.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = Map.of(" ", 18, "foo", 14, "abcd",
        20, "ab", 10, "efgh", 3, "rstuv", 14);
```

- Then I would define a `Predicate<Entry<String, Integer>>` to reduce the clutter of the stream construct.  Note that since you are checking for `length < 3` the condition for a single space can be omitted.  If you meant check for a blank String, you can use `!val.getKey().isBlank()` as the condition.
- `reduce` takes an initial argument followed by a `BinaryOperator` as an accumulator.  In this case the accumulation is a concatenation of the mapped strings.  `String::concat` meets the requirements and is used here to fulfill the operation.

```
Predicate<Entry<String, Integer>> check =
        val -> val.getValue() >= 10
                && val.getKey().length() > 3;
```

Then it is just a matter of streaming the `EntrySet`.

```
String result = map.entrySet().stream().filter(check)
         .map(e -> e.getKey().toLowerCase() + " - " + e.getValue() + "\n")
         .reduce("", String::concat);

Systemm.out.print(result);
```

Prints the following.

```
abcd - 20
rstuv - 14
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation a lot )) I just saw your response and although I had solved this problem long time ago,, I discovered some new things for me :)

Comment: @czauto.  Thanks!  BTW, not certain if you knew this but you can't accept two answers.   No problem though.

Answer (score 0):

To have a full use of stream functionalities You need to use stream, filter and reduce functions as follow:

```
// Get the stream from entrySet
String result = map.entrySet().stream()    
      // Filter entries based on your condition
      .filter(val ->  val.getValue() >= 10 
                           && !Objects.equals(val.getKey(), " ") 
                           && val.getKey().length() > 3)  
       // Apply the reduce to combine filtered entries in a single string     
      .reduce("", (stats, val) -> stats 
                                  + val.getKey().toLowerCase() 
                                  + " - " 
                                  + val.getValue() 
                                  + "\n");
```

The [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) method applied to a Collection give a new Stream of the item present in the set:

> Returns a sequential Stream with this collection as its source.

The [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) method appplied on the stream:

> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream that match the given predicate.

The [reduce](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) function on the stream object:

> Performs a reduction on the elements of this stream, using the provided identity value and an associative accumulation function, and returns the reduced value

Comment: now I'm getting Bad return type in lambda expression: String cannot be converted to Entry<String, Integer> error

Comment: @czauto The ternary expression (a > b ? 1 : 0) is not a statement but a value. It uses a conditional expression to determine a value (1 or 0). So you might be putting a value where you should be putting a statement, or vice versa.

Comment: The 2-arg `reduce` function won't work here, as a `BinaryOperator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>` is expected while you're passing a `BiFunction<String, Map.Entry<String, Integer>, String>`. You need [the 3-arg overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-).

Comment: What about [`Collectors.joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining%28%29)?

Answer (score 0):

Good job using the forEach method. It's good practice to use streams and the stream API.

Here's a very simple program that does something similar to what you want to do.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("aaaa", 1);
        map.put("bbbb", 2);
        map.put("cccc", 3);
        map.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k + ": " + v));
    }
}
```

Now we can compile and run the code.

```
% javac Test.java
% java Test
aaaa: 1
bbbb: 2
cccc: 3
```

Now, what's the error in your code?

The error is this. The Map.forEach method takes a BiConsumer. The BiConsumer operation takes two input arguments (k and v) and returns no result. You are using a BiConsumer operation to return a result in a ternary expression. The BiConsumer operation has a return type of void. So what you can do is... you can execute code inside of the BiConsumer operation (like I did in my example) but you cannot return a result in the BiConsumer operation (which you are trying to do).

You can read about the Map.forEach method and the BiConsumer functional operation in the Java docs.

1. [Java docs for the Map.forEach method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#forEach(java.util.function.BiConsumer))
2. [Java docs for the BiConsumer operation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html)